# Grails - how to catch and warn user about invalid data source credentials

Tags: mysql, database, grails

I am developing a grails application which will use external config file with data needed for grails data source connection. I would like to show in GUI (at first access as a warning message or whatever similar) that credentials written in config file are invalid. Currently i've got no idea how to implement it cause the error is thrown before accessing the controller and the application fails to start.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Application will not start if creds are not correct.

Comment: Take a look at this post by Burt Beckwith: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1565

Comment: Thanks Andrew I'll take a look at link you posted. I really would like to show user that creds for DB are invalid since they are configurable at installation point and also could change on DB side when application is already deployed (this is probably easiest to handle).